# Selecting different UITableViewCells from indexPath alone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a scenario where upon selecting a `UITableViewCell` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I need to load and get the information from a different `UITableViewCell`.

I'm registering and using two different xibs to be used as my tableViewCells to allow for some more customization.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.TABLE_ROW_HEIGHT = 66;

    self.tblView.delegate = self;
    self.tblView.dataSource = self;

    [self.tblView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BasicCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BasicCell"];

    [self.tblView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DetailCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DetailCell"];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Property of the view controller which is an IndexPath
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath;

    BasicModel *basicModel = [self.models objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.apiClient detailModelSearch:basicModel.id];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if([self.selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]){

        return 400.0f;
    }

    return 66.0f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    BasicModel *basicModel = [self.models objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *tableCell = nil;

    if([self.selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]){

        DetailCell *detailCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DetailCell"];

        tableCell = detailCell;
    }

    else{

        BasicCell *basicCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BasicCell"];

        tableCell = basicCell;
    }

    return tableCell;
}

-(APIClient *)apiClient{

    if(!_apiClient){

        _apiClient = [APIClient new];

        __weak ViewController *_self = self;

        _apiClient.detailModelSearchFinished = ^(DetailModel *detailModel){

            _self.detailModel = detailModel;

           //Problem is here 
           DetailCell *cell = [_self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_self.selectedIndexPath;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [_self.tblView beginUpdates];
                [_self.tblView endUpdates];
                [_self.tblView reloadData];
            });
        };

    }

    return _apiClient;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.models.count;
}
```

The basic structure is as follows.

1. App load and loads all BasicModels into the the models array.
2. User selects a cell which prompts an API detail search request
3. When detail search request is finished, the callback returns a DetailModel
4. What should happen next is since I know the selected index path of the touched cell, I want to use the DetailCell instead of the BasicCell to present the detailedInformation that comes from the DetailModel. My problem is when I call

   DetailCell *cell = [_self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_self.selectedIndexPath;

I always receive the BasicCell that does not have the detailed view components I need to bind the detailModel to.

BasicCell xib

[image]

Detail Cell Xib

[image]

Table View Normal:

[image]

Table View Expanded with detail Cel xib

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the same tableview should be transformed to detailcell or detailcell should appear below the basiccell such that it looks part of the selectedindex...

Comment: The line you say causes the problem, `DetailCell *cell = [_self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_self.selectedIndexPath` doesn't actually do anything, since you never do anything with "cell". You shouldn't need that line anyway. If your selectedIndexPath is set correctly, reloading your table view should give you the detail cell since you have that if-else clause in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You should put a log inside that "if" to see if it's being executed.

Comment: Yup I just figured this out too lol, good timing. Yeah I had to reload the data and then call for the ExpandedCell and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now is very clear. 
I can think of two ways, one is if you don't care about fancy animations just remove the (basic) cell and insert a new (detail) cell at the same index path, only after tho you have updated the model as well and perform the eventual type checks. 
Quick and dirty, if you want something more clean you may want to refactor the model objects using polimorfism or other suitable patterns.

Another way is to update directly the cell with the received data. You may apply some fancy animations but loosing possibly some performances advantages.

Comment: @zic10 i have updated the answer. If on the right track i may give more details.

Comment: I've added some more photos showing what the process looks like. I've considered using a polymorphic approach with a BaseCell and then polymorphically deciding which type of cell to use but since I can show the DetailCell in the tableView I don't understand why I cant use that sameIndexPath to get a reference to the DetailTableCell in the api search complete block response.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution actually. Reload data must be called before I can grab the expanded cell. Simple as this:

```
           [_self.tblView beginUpdates];
            [_self.tblView endUpdates];
            [_self.tblView reloadData];

               DetailCell *expandedCell = (DetailCell *) [_self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_self.selectedIndex];

             expandedCell.lblData.text = @"IT WORKS!";


        });
```